# Java replaceAll with newline symbol

Tags: java, regex, newline

the newline symbol \n is causing me a bit of trouble when i try to detect and replace it:
This works fine:

```
String x = "Bob was a bob \\n";
String y = x.replaceAll("was", "bob");
System.out.println(y);
```

butt this code does not give the desired result

```
String x = "Bob was a bob \\n";
String y = x.replaceAll("\n", "bob");
System.out.println(y);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"Bob was a bob \\n"` becomes literally `Bob was a bob \n`

There is no newline to replace in the input string. Are you trying to replace a newline character or the escape sequence `\\n`?

Comment: I'm trying to replace the new line with another string eg "A B \n C" would become "A B Y C"

Comment: As I said, there is NO newline character in your input string.

Comment: Your input string does not have a newline in it. It has a backslash followed by a letter n. Meanwhile, your regex does not have an escape sequence for a newline in it. It has an actual newline.

Answer (score 3):

This works as expected.

```
String str = "A B \n C";
String newStr = str.replaceAll("\\n","Y");
System.out.println(newStr);
```

Prints:-

```
A B Y C
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String x = "Bob was a bob \\n";
String y = x.replaceAll("was", "bob");
System.out.println(y);
```

one problem here:  "\n" is not newline symbol. It should be:

```
String x = "Bob was a bob \n";// \n is newline symbol, on window newline is \r\n
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?:

```
x.replaceAll("\\n", "bob");
```

You should escape the new line char before using it in replace function.

Comment: In the regex string you can use either `\n` or `\\n`.  After the Java compiler is done with it, the regex compiler will see an actual linefeed in the first case, or the escape sequence backslash-'n' in the second.  Either way it will match a linefeed.  As some of the others have pointed out, it's the backslash-backslash-'n' in the target string that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your input string does not contain a new line.  Instead it contains "\n".  See the corrected input string below.

```
String x = "Bob was a bob \n";
String y = x.replaceAll("\n", "bob");
System.out.println(y);
```

Answer (score -3):

UPDATED:

I have modified it to work with multiple ocurrences of \n. Note that this may not be very efficient.

```
public static String replaceBob(String str,int index){
    char arr[] = str.toCharArray();
    for(int i=index; i<arr.length; i++){
        if( arr[i]=='\\' && i<arr.length && arr[i+1]=='n' ){
            String temp = str.substring(0, i)+"bob";
            String temp2 = str.substring(i+2,str.length());
            str = temp + temp2;
            str = replaceBob(str,i+2);
            break;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

I tried with this and it worked

```
String x = "Bob was a bob \\n 123 \\n aaa \\n";
System.out.println("result:"+replaceBob(x, 0));
```

The first time you call the function use an index of 0.

Comment: Pick a reason: 1.) it's much more complicated than it needs to be; 2.) it's horribly inefficient; 3.) it's gratuitously recursive; 4.) it has an off-by-one error in the `if` condition; 5.) followed by an off-by-two error inside the `if` block; 6.) it uses string concatenation instead of a StringBuilder; or 7.) it doesn't solve the OP's problem, which is that (s)he's trying to replace newlines in a string that doesn't contain any.